# I cannot call jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to call jquery in my js file (app.js) so i can use jquery in  my nav.js, but i have an error in browser console :

```
app.js:1479 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at eval (nav.js:4)
at Object../src/assets/script/nav.js (app.js:61)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1476)
at fn (app.js:1687)
at eval (app.js:2)
at Module../src/assets/app.js (app.js:41)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1476)
at app.js:2533
at app.js:2537
```

This is my app.js :

```
import './script/nav.js';
import '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';
```

This is my nav.js

```
console.log("test");
    // Close all items when a current item is open
    $('.nav-link > button').on('click', function (e) {
        var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.nav-collapse');
        var notToHide = $(this).parents('.nav-link').find('.nav-collapse');
        $(".nav-collapse").not(EltToToggle).removeClass("show");

        // aria-expanded toggle
        if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "false") {
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
            $('.nav-collapse').prev().attr('aria-expanded', false);
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try moving the jquery import above nav.js import?

Comment: actually the Path import `'../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';`  is working, but i don't know why i have this error : '$ is not defined ..'

Comment: import * as $ from 'jquery'
write this statement to import jquery in your page

Comment: make sure that jquery exist in your package.json

Comment: @Parth i still have the error, and yes i have jquery in package.json :(

Comment: `import nav .. import jquery` - must be `import jquery ... import nav`

Comment: i did it, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added jquery as below in angular.json :

```
"projects": {
    "clientApp": {
        "architect": {
        "build": {
              "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
         }
         }
     }
}
```

Or you can directly add in index.html with script

Comment: im not using angular, it's a pure html css and js/kquery

Comment: ok can you please share your code of block where you added jquery (Means html)

Answer (score 0):

```
in nav.js file add "declare var $" as shown below;

declare var $;
console.log("test");
    // Close all items when a current item is open
    $('.nav-link > button').on('click', function (e) {
        var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.nav-collapse');
        var notToHide = $(this).parents('.nav-link').find('.nav-collapse');
        $(".nav-collapse").not(EltToToggle).removeClass("show");

        // aria-expanded toggle
        if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "false") {
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
            $('.nav-collapse').prev().attr('aria-expanded', false);
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i didn't understand : declare var $;

Comment: i have error when i add `declare var $;' i have never heard of this syntax before :/